# vim comment out every line of text containing a pattern using the 'global' command

Tags: substitute, comments, global-command, plugin-vim-commentary

In my file containing LaTeX source code, I wish to comment out all the lines matching a pattern (specifically, the pattern that I am interested in is `\draw`, including the `\` character).

I have `magic` mode enabled.  I think a potential solution would be to use the `global` command i.e. something along the lines of

```
:g/\\draw/command
```

I am unsure of the `command` that achieves my task. I would like to seek your help through either of the methods below:

1. I have Tim Pope's `commentary` plugin which provides the `gc` mapping, which works in normal mode. However, this does not work in `ex` mode.
2. Maybe use the normal mode `I` command and use the comment character for LaTeX (the percent `%` character) on those lines matched by the global command.

Please let me know if a simpler alternative exists in addition to the ones mentioned above, I am of course glad to learn about it too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `g/\\draw/s/^/%/` to insert a percent sign at the start of every line containing the text `\draw`. `s/^/%/` means *replace the empty string at the start of the line with a percent sign*.

If you want to put the percent sign after any leading white space---which is more similar to how the normal command `I` works---, use `g/\\draw/s/^\s*/&%/` instead. `s/^\s*/&%/` means *replace a possibly empty string of whitespace characters at the start of the line with the string itself, followed by a percent sign*.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `:g/\\draw/norm gcc`

From `:help norm`:

> Execute Normal mode commands {commands}.  This makes      it possible
> to execute Normal mode commands typed on the command-line.
> {commands} are executed like they are typed.